# Why is the post type on the search result page random?

Tags: theme-development, search, post-type

So I think I might be doing something fundamentally wrong in my Wordpress themes since this issue seems to crop up every once in a while and I don't know why.

So basically I created search.php and I use relevanssi to sort my search results by relevancy. When I search for "camera" and do `echo get_post_type();` I get "reviews" but if I search for "test" and do `echo get_post_type();` I get "articles".

I tried injecting wp_reset_query() just about everywhere to try and see if I was changing it randomly but it's not that. I think WP is confused since my search result page isn't really linked with any specific page so it is not set to a specific post type. Is there a way to have it be a page?

Any help is appreciated

edit:

I added the code below. In the var_dump I just see the query stuff but get_post_type() is different on every search term.

search.php:

```
<?php
get_header();

global $query_string;

$query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
$search_query = array();

foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
    $query_split = explode("=", $string);
    $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
} // foreach

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
    's' => $search_query['s']
);

echo get_post_type() .'<br>';
var_dump($args);

$search = new WP_Query($args);

if( $search->have_posts() ) {
    while( $search->have_posts() ) {
        $search->the_post();

        include( get_template_directory() . '/includes/templates/search_result.inc.php' );      

    }
    wp_reset_query();
}
?>

<a id="ld-more" href="#search">Load more search results</a>
<?php
get_footer();
```

Comment: where do you call `get_post_type` (show us the code), and why are the results you're getting unexpected (what do you expect it to return)?

Comment: I think it is more likely that you are confused about how WordPress works :) Post your relevant code please.

Comment: To be more specific: please post your `search.php` template code.

Comment: Oops sorry guys, search.php content would be extremely handy! I edited the original question with the code. I think this might be a situation where I've misunderstood something in theme development and I've been doing it wrong all this time (hence why I'm trying to solve this once and for all haha)

Comment: Next question: why are you hijacking the default search query? If the sole purpose is to modify the posts per page, then `pre_get_posts` is your new best friend. :)

Comment: I just copy posted stuff from the codex (http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page) and then changed how many results I wanted to display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is almost certainly that you've created a second query. That query is going to be out of sync with the main query, hence you are getting unexpected results.

From what I can see, you aren't really doing anything that the main query doesn't already do, so I think you really only need the Loop itself.

```
get_header();

if( have_posts() ) {
    while( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

        include( get_template_directory() . '/includes/templates/search_result.inc.php' );      

    }
    wp_reset_query();
}
?>

<a id="ld-more" href="#search">Load more search results</a>
<?php
get_footer();
```

Comment: Hmm well that solved the problem where I had no results but the post type is still random. Is there a way (and must I) tell wordpress that my search.php is a "page" the same way you set a page to be your blog and your front page?

Comment: @Gazillion a search results page isn't a page, [it's a search](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_search). the post type isn't random, it's the post type of post(s) in your search results. maybe you should back up a few steps and explain *why* you want it to behave as a page.

Comment: Hmm I guess I assumed that it had to be associated with something. In my header code I have a check for a specific sidebar that only appears for a specific post type and since the post type seemed random I would sometimes get the sidebar and sometimes not. Seeing how this is the correct behaviour I just added an is_search check and it works now. I'll just have to be more mindful in the future. I'll mark this answer as correct since it fixed another issue I was having! :)